# Estimate minimum detectable effect using simulations

Tags: simulation, statistical-power

In a [study](https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaneurology/article-abstract/2805036) investigating a time-to-event outcome in a propensity score matched sample, the authors state the following in their methods: "Where no evidence of difference between the compared groups was found, the minimum detectable effect at α = 0.05 and 1 − β = 0.80 was estimated with 200 simulations"

How does such a simulation work (is the study data resampled? if so, in what way?) and how can you arrive at a minimum detectable effect from these simulations?

Comment: Paywall. I (and others?) can't read the study.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, it is a paywalled article.. But since they do not provide any information on the simulations, it is not really relevant to the current question. I decided to provide it more as a reference and the curious reader can still get an idea of the study design from the abstract.